# Thread terminating when running a function in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am programing a midi maker that you can make a song through the console (and later a window) but I'm having a thread issue. When I want the song to start, the thread starts but it doesn't run the function that has the song player. I copy and pasted the base code from a working project and I cant figure out why it is not running. IT prints "setting up" but not "running". Here is my code for the function:

```
public void songStart() throws InterruptedException {
    int temp;
    channelVolume = new int[channelNotes.length][channelNotes[0].length];
    if (channelNotes.length < userChannels.length) {
        temp = channelNotes.length;
    } else {
        temp = userChannels.length;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < userChannelNotesNumLongest; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < temp; i++) {
            if (channelNotes[i][j] == r) {
                channelVolume[i][j] = 0;
            } else if (advanced == false){
                channelVolume[i][j]=50;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("running");
    for (int i = 0; i < temp; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < userChannelNotesNumLongest; j++) {
            noteOn(userChannels[i],channelNotes[i][j],channelVolume[i][j]);
            Thread.sleep(interval);
            noteOff(userChannels[i],channelNotes[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the code for the thread:

```
public class SongThread extends Thread {
    public void run(){
        try {
            Main.song.songStart();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
    }
}
```

Here is were the code runs the thread (i have a print in there that does print)

```
if (userInput.equals("start")) {
        System.out.println("setting up");
        SongThread thread = new SongThread();
        thread.start();
    }
```

Note: everything works fine until the thread tries to run the function, then it just stops running it. Also, it is the same base code in the other project that works fine. The function that is displayed is in a class instance in `Main` called `song`. And I don't get an error from the catch. Keep in mind that I copy and pasted the code from a working project and the only thing different is that it is not static and runs the instance from the `Main` class

I have tried making the `songStart` function static with everything inside as well. I have used all the combinations of try / catch an d throws exceptions in the thread and the function (where the thread didn't have a try / catch or throws and where the function has a try / catch or a throws). the way I have it in my working project is a throws in the function and a try / catch in the thread.

Comment: What is `Main`?  What does `noteOn` and `noteOff` do?  When you want to play audio you have to flush the line (so it forces a write to the sound card which will output the data).  That's for audio playback (like from a `.wav` file) so I don't know if that's relevant for playing MIDI audio.

Comment: Please include the code that calls `start()` on an instance of `SongThread`.

Comment: Do you see any difference if you call `thread.join()` after starting it?

Comment: @Jared `Main` is the class that has the `public static void main(String[] args)` function, `noteOn` and `noteOff` are functions that I made that use the default synthesizer midi channel function the play a note: `<MidiChannel>.noteOn/noteOff(<note>)`(I made them so it would be easier to manage).

Comment: @NG No, When I call `thread.join()` It does the same thing when it wasn't called.

Comment: As far as i can see, the `Main.song.songStart();` wont work since its a static call call to a non static function.

Comment: How do I call it in a non static way?

Comment: @Dileep, it looks like `Main` has a static member variable `song`  which is an instance of whatever class `songStart` is defined on.  That would certainly allow `songStart` to be called this way (not that I'm saying it's a preferable way of calling it though).

Comment: @Zennsworld, have you tried debugging this yet?  See this article for some good advice: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @SimonC I have attempted to debug it a couple of times, I personally cant find whats wrong with the function call.

Comment: @Zennsworld, it would greatly assist the people trying to debug your code if you include *all* of the things you have tried to track down the problem.